# can VB6 be installed onto Azure VM Windows Server 2010 R8

Tags: windows, azure, vb6, vb6-migration

First warning is "This program has compatibility issues".

Then, it hangs in "Setup is updating your system..." and its window title reads Not Responding.

and then error msg:
"Install wizard for VB 6 Pro
"..setup failed"

Answer (score 1):

On a newer OS (Windows 8/10), the VB6 IDE installer will hang if `Data Access Components` is included.

Select `Custom` install type and uncheck `Data Access Components`

See FortyPoundHead's [Install VB6 on Windows 8](http://www.fortypoundhead.com/showcontent.asp?artid=23916) article for more details that should relate to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the runtime in windows server 2012, but you cannot install de IDE , review the OS Support here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikosan/archive/2012/04/20/support-statement-for-visual-basic-6-0-on-windows-8.aspx

Also, ins your post I mean is Windows Server 2012 not Server 2010